# CodeIgniter Join 3 table and separate duplicate item name with comma with same id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have 3 table :

*table P

| id | Kode P | NamaPaket | Durasi | Harga |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | P004 | Main 1 Jam | 1 | 30000 |
| 22 | P005 | Main Sepuasnya | 5 | 50000 |
| 17 | P004 | Main 1 Jam | 1 | 30000 |
| 13 | P005 | Promo 2 Jam | 5 | 50000 |
| 24 | P004 | Vc.Gatis 2 Jam | 1 | 0 |
| 25 | P005 | P.Polio Posynd | 5 | 25000 |
| 26 | P004 | Promo Main Sep | 1 | 50000 |

*table B

| id | id P | Barcode | Jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 20 | T0001 | 1 |
| 14 | 19 | T0001 | 1 |
| 21 | 26 | T0001 | 1 |
| 20 | 22 | T0001 | 1 |
| 22 | 26 | K0001 | 1 |

*table D

| id | Barcode | Nama Barang | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | T0001 | Kaos Kaki | 9 |
| 14 | T0001 | Teh Btl250ml | 7 |

im making personal web application with CI 3 and php,
this is my model :

```
    public function paket_bundling()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('tbpaket')
                        ->join('tbbarangpaket', 'tbbarangpaket.idpaket=tbpaket.id', 'left')
                        ->join('tbbarang', 'tbbarang.barcode=tbbarangpaket.barcode', 'left')
                        ->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

controller :

```
    public function Paket()
    {
        $data = [
            'judul' => 'Master Data',
            'subjudul' => 'Paket',
            'menu' => 'masterdata',
            'submenu' => 'paket',
            'page' => 'v_paket',
            'list_paket' => $this->ModelData->get_data('tbpaket')->result(),
            'bundling' => $this->ModelData->paket_bundling(),
        ];
        return $this->load->view('v_template', $data);
    }
```

view :

```
<div class="card card-warning">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">List Paket</h3>
    </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th>Kode Paket</th>
            <th>Nama Paket</th>
            <th>Harga</th>
            <th>Durasi</th>
            <th>Jumlah</th>
            <th>Bundling</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($bundling as $pkt) : ?>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <td><?= $pkt->KodePaket ?></td>
          <td><?= $pkt->NamaPaket ?></td>
          <td>Rp <?= number_format($pkt->Harga) ?></td>
          <td><?= $pkt->Durasi ?> jam</td>
          <td><?= $pkt->Jumlah ?></td>
          <td><?= $pkt->NamaBarang ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my result for now :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJyG7.png)

how can i union same item id and separate comma bundling item ? like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5keN.jpg)

thanks,